# App leaves Virtual file(package name) after uninstall (Android)

Tags: android

I've stored database at `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/(My package Name)`.

After uninstalling, App leaves a virtual file(or folder).
It can not be deleted with file explorer.

And the Virtual file's fixed date is `01-01-1970`.
And no authority for delete,read,write.

This doesn't happen all the time.
Some users reported this problem before. But I couldn't solve it because I didn't know what the problem was. Now.. it happened to me :(

Because of this, some users and I cannot reinstall my app.
I need to store the database at `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/(My package Name)` so database can be deleted when people uninstall my app.

Maybe this didn't happen when the app is uninstalling. 
It could have happened during installation.

What can be done about this problem?

Comment: Does this happen on a specific device?

Comment: This happens on many devices.

Comment: The external storage is not supposed to have file permissions, so you are either misunderstanding the problem, or running on devices where the external storage is not properly implemented.  Or a third possibility - you are hard coding a path (mistake) that is not that of the external storage, and it is falling through to a unix file system with permissions.  On the simple side, it's possible ddms explorer won't delete a non-empty folder.